# time zone don't work visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, timezone

As in title . I want to add to my timer a time zone .
I try this :

```
int G = DateTime.Now.Kind;
```

but it throw an error .
How i could check timezone in winforms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `DateTime.Now.Kind` returns a `DateTimeKind` which is an enum and you have to explicitly cast it to `int`:

```
int G = (int)DateTime.Now.Kind;
```

or:

```
DateTimeKind G = DateTime.Now.Kind;
```

But as the others said, it doesn't return the timezone. You should use:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `DateTime` doesn't contain real timezone information.

Try to use [`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx) property instead of.

> Gets the time zone of the current computer.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/tjsdw0).

Also, if you really interested timezones in .NET Framework, you should really read [`Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx) which is awesome article in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Kind` is not about timezone.It is enumeration which shows what kind of date: `Local, UTC,Uncpecified`.